# mongodb how to change array position

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a mongodb document which has an array. Is there a way to rearrange the order of array element?

Example - I have 10 elements in array and I need element in position 7 to be moved to position 2.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: And what happens to the element at position 2? You could also look at the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/)

Comment: Entire stack moves down...

Comment: You've tagged this with both Java and NodeJS.  Where do you want to perform this operation?  In application code or via DB shell?

Comment: This is a node.js website. I need to perform this is through  application based on user request.

Answer (score 0):

If this is done within Node, one option is to use [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) along with [splice](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_array_MongooseArray-splice):

For example, to remove the element at position 7 (remember, 0th based):

```
var position7 = doc.subdocs.splice(6, 1);
```

Then to insert it earlier in the array, at position 2:

```
doc.subdocs.splice(1, 0, position7[0]);
```

More information on the splice function can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice